# Prevent terraform function 'templatefile' from outputting heredoc

Tags: bash, terraform, heredoc, terraform-template-file, multipass

I have a [cloud-init](https://cloud-init.io/) config file to be used to spin up VMs in AWS using [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) that I also want to run locally using [Multipass](https://multipass.run/) for testing and debugging.

The cloud-init file includes some shell scripts which Terraform requires to be rewritten such that they refer to variables as `$$var` instead of just `$var`. It also uses a template variable for the hostname.

To be able to use the same config file on both cloud and locally, I figured that I could use the following command to expand the templating and start the Multipass VM without manual string replacements:

```
terraform console <<< "templatefile(\"cloud-init.yaml\", {hostname: \"test\"})" | multipass launch -n test --cloud-init -
```

But it turns out that the `templatefile` function wraps its output in heredoc:

```
<<EOT
... contents ...
EOT
```

Multipass of course doesn't understand this syntax and prints the (rather unhelpful) error message:

```
launch failed: operator[] call on a scalar (key: "users")
```

Ideally, the Terraform command should be able to render the file without heredoc wrapper. But alternatively, is there a shell trick that would make this work?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little gross, but piping the contents through `sed '1d;$d'` removes the first and last lines which contain the heredoc markers:

```
terraform console <<< 'templatefile("cloud-init.yaml", {hostname: "test"})' | sed '1d;$d' | multipass launch -n test --cloud-init -
```

This is of course fragile as e.g. whitespace changes could break the assumptions of where the markers are. This solution should therefore be considered a hack/workaround in lack of a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but better late than never. My scenario was taking a k8s yaml file and using it as a template file for the kubernetes_manifest provider, and ran into the same problem of the heredoc formatting breaking the provider. Ended up using `yamldecode()` and it cleared out the heredoc formatting.

```
manifest = yamldecode(templatefile("./hpa.yaml", var.hpavalues))
```

Not the cleanest depending on the format you get the file in. in your case you'd probably have to do something like:

```
terraform console <<< 'yamlencode(yamldecode(templatefile("cloud-init.yaml", {hostname: "test"})))' | multipass launch -n test --cloud-init -
```

But there are a couple options, yamldecode(), jsondecode(), and their respective encode partners.